# Python can't find installed module

Tags: python, python-3.x

I successfully installed the module geocoder:

> Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in
> c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages (from
> requests->geocoder) (4.0.0) Installing collected packages: ratelim,
> geocoder Successfully installed geocoder-1.38.1 ratelim-0.1.6

When I try to create a Python file that includes `import geocoder`, I get the error `Import "geocoder" could not be resolved`.

The relevant path is included in sys.path:

C:\Users\myname\Downloads
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python39.zip
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\DLLs
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin

Why isn't Python able to resolve this module?

Thanks

Comment: Please look if there is a folder named `geocoder` in `c:\users\myname\appdata\roaming\python\python39\site-packages` (or some similar named folder). If so, please tell me which files / folders you see in the `geocoder` folder.

Comment: you may have the most common problem - you have two Pythons installed and you install module in one Python but you run code with other Python. Pythons don't share modules and every version need own module. You chould check in code which version it uses to run code - i.e. `print( os.executable )` - and it should show `c:/full/path/to/python.exe` which you should use to install module - ie. `c:/full/path/to/python.exe -m pip install ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either `geocoder` is installed to other than Python3.9 version installation (e.g. python 3.7) or `geocoder` is not in the path of your python module.

Try to install the library using specific Python pip package manager (e.g. pip3.9) and run the module you develop using specific Python version (e.g. Python3.9)